# How to apply database updates after deployment?

Tags: deployment

i know this is an often asked question on these boards. And usually the question has been about how to manage the changes being made to the database before you even get around to deploy them.Mostly the answer has been to script the database and save it under sourcecontrol and then any additional updates are saved as scripts under version control too.(ex. [Tool to upgrade SQL Express database after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634740/tool-to-upgrade-sql-express-database-after-deployment))

my question is when is it best to apply the database updates , in the installer or when the new version first runs and connects to the database? note this is a WinApp that is deployed to customers each have their own databases.

Comment: update: this is a client server app.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to add to the script: Back up the database (or at least the tables you're changing!) before applying the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As a user I think I'd prefer it happens during the install, and going a little further that the installer can roll itself back in the event of a failure.  My thinking here is that if I am installing an update, I'd like to know when the update is done that it actually is done and has succeeded.  I don't want a message coming up the next time I run it informing me that something failed and I've potentially lost all my data.  I would assume that a system admin would probably also appreciate install time feedback (of course, that doesn't matter if your web app isn't something that will be installed on a network).  Also, as ראובן said, backing up the database would be a nice convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said much about the architecture of the application, but since an installer is involved I assume it's a client/server application.

If you have a server installer, that's where you want to put it, since the database structure is only going to change once.  Since the client installers are going to need to know about the change, it would be nice to have a way to detect the database version change, and for the old client to be able to download the client update from the server automatically and apply it.

If you only have a client installer, I still think it's better to put it there (maybe as a custom action that fires off the executable for updating the database).  But it really isn't going to matter, because conceptually one installer or first-time user of the new version is going to have to fire off the changes to the database anyway.  The database changes are going to put structural locks on the database so, in practical terms, everyone is going to have to be kicked off the system at that time for the database update to be applied.

Of course, this is all BS if it's not client-server.