# Dealing with Schema Updates in nHibernate/Fluent nHibernate after Deployment

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In writing an application that runs on Fluent Nhibernate/Nhibernate, something has me a bit concerned. I suppose this would be true of any ORM (and even without using an ORM), but what is the ... I guess the word is 'field of study' that relates to the best practices and methods for updating a database after deployment?

In nHibernate, I establish a SessionFactory and have an initial run where it writes the database out based on the mappings. That's fine and good, I can even write the database out manually. But what about when my client comes back and wants something new added? Can I append to the database without losing my data? I am completely new to all of this and it has been troubling me since the start of this project, and I really do not know what direction to go to make sure I can manage the program after it is deployed.

I have looked at other stack overflow questions that I could find regarding this topic - one of which did not even have an accepted answer (though the question itself was kind of vague), but I did discover the tool http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/ from the question
[Tool to upgrade SQL Express database after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634740/tool-to-upgrade-sql-express-database-after-deployment) though I am wondering just how good of a 'strategy' that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options, use [the AutoMapping feature in Fluent NHibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping) to minimize the mapping code you write. If your schema changes comply with the AutoMap conventions then you only need to work with the corresponding domain object changes.

Another less optimal option is to take a database first approach and have something [like MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1505) automatically generate the domain classes and NHibernate mapping files from the schema. This works if you have complete control of the database schema and it can be made to implement a good domain model design (both conditions which very rarely ever happen...)

In either approach, [these tools can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313/net-migrations-engine) handle the database scripting needed to "migrate" the schema changes to a new version

Comment: well, I know about the auto-mapping. What I am more concerned about is if the schema changes, I am afraid that it might automatically change my database and dump my data.

Comment: Unless you have written code in your application to apply schemas scripts generated by NHibernate, these will not be applied automatically. These .NET [database migration tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313/net-migrations-engine) can help update databases with schema changes without losing any existing data.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, after deployment you have to manually keep your db structure up-to-date.
that means that whenever you add / change your db structure, you do so using a script with DDL commands.
when you're ready to deploy, you just run those DDL scripts against your production db.
for example, if you add a 'bar' column to your 'foo' table, your script would be something like (pseudo-code):

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN 'bar' int(32) not null default(0);
```

Comment: The question obviously implies an automatic solution